# Checking if two expressions are related

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

Is it possible in mathematica to check if two expressions may be able to be written in terms of the other? The expressions I had in mind were of the form $$\alpha = \frac{1-x}{1-y}\,\,\,\,,\,\,\ \beta = \frac{1+x}{1+y}$$ and was wondering if it's possible to find a relation $$\alpha = f(\beta)?$$

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the answer for the given system is **No**.

Defining the equations first:

```
eqns = {a == (1-x)/(1-y), b == (1+x)/(1+y)};
```

We can use `Eliminate` to try and suss out a relation which does not depend on `x` or `y`.

```
Eliminate[eqns, {x, y}]
```

> True

However, `Eliminate` returns `True`. This means that `a` and `b` can be chosen independently of each other, disproving the existence of a relation of the form $\alpha = f(\beta)$ immediately. If that's not convincing, however, you can use `Reduce` to find out the precise conditions for which a solution for `a` exists:

```
Reduce[eqns, a, {x, y}]
```

> (b == 1 && a == 1) || (-1 + a) (a - b) (-1 + b) != 0

So if `a` and `b` are both 1, or so long as the other expression is not 0, any pairing of `a` and `b` should be possible. You can use `FindInstance` to find a few, if you wish:

```
FindInstance[eqns /. {a->4, b->2}, {x, y}]
FindInstance[eqns /. {a->5, b->2}, {x, y}]
```

> {{x -> 5, y -> 2}}
>
> {{x -> 13/3, y -> 5/3}}

Answer (score 1):

Solve $\beta$ for $x=x(\beta,y)$:

```
S = Solve[β == (1 + x)/(1 + y), x]
```

> {{x -> -1 + β + y β}}

Use this list of solutions to express $\alpha=\alpha(\beta,y)$:

```
α = FullSimplify[(1 - x)/(1 - y) /. S]
```

> {(-2 + β + y β)/(-1 + y)}

Pick those solutions where $\alpha$ depends only on $\beta$ but not on $y$:

```
Select[α, FreeQ[y]]
```

> {}

No solutions found in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FindInstance` to generate a simple counter-example to the hypothesis that `a` is a function of `b`

```
a = (1 - x)/(1 - y);
b = (1 + x)/(1 + y);

FindInstance[{a == 2, b == 1/2}, {x, y}]

(* {{x -> -(1/3), y -> 1/3}} *)

FindInstance[{a != 2, b == 1/2}, {x, y}]

(* {{x -> 1, y -> 3}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is because if $a = f(b)$ existed then by definition it cannot be one to many.